# Why is it necessary to scan entire body in Vipassana?

Tags: vipassana, lay-buddhism, tibetan-buddhism

Mr Goenka teaches that there are six senses including mind, and that when we observe them in vipassana we eradicate our sankaras.

My question is, nearly all my senses are on my face: like taste, smell, hearing, and seeing. Only "touch" and "mind" I am not sure of.

So why not just focus on the my facial sensations, and do it smartly?

Otherwise, what is the use of observing my legs' sensation, when I am fighting with anger, frustration, love, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Otherwise, what is the use of observing my legs' sensation, when I am fighting with anger, frustration, love, etc.?

When you are angry the distribution of the sensations through the body may take one form. When in love another. There will be places where sensations are more intense, but nevertheless there is sensations throughout.

> So why not just focus on ...
>
> Why is it necessary to scan entire body in Vipassana?

You have to understand the full sphere of experience. You have to understand all sensations in the body. If you move from more gross or intense sensations to another, you will never understand the more subtle sensations. You have to come to a state where you experience any sensation in the body, always, and though the body. This is how you will know the whole sphere of experiences is unsatisfactory.

> touch

Throughout your body - skin

> mind

head and around the heart

Also keep in mind. When something happens in the mind also bodily sensations arise. When something happens in the body metal sensations arise.

Comment: What if i keep on saying everything is impermanent and believe in that what you said is true, Do i still need to **Know myself** that this body or sensations are impermanent.

Comment: What you lean, try to verify and validate it experientially. You have to contemplate it is impermanent.

Comment: May i ask if you have seen earth, water, air and fire in each atoms and how mind is entangled with them as claimed by Goenka, **Also have you seen what is permanent?**, beyond atoms

Comment: What matters is you have to see. Another's experience does not add value to your empirical understanding.

Comment: One Night I was so scared, any little sound makes my heart pound so fast, I tried to be in equanimity, nothing worked for like 3-4 hours. **What could have worked?** and I believe it happened to many students once. and every one had cried at-least once in 10 days, why is that sir?

Comment: Insight meditation is what you observe just watch attentively, no two individual will see the same. And never think before you have such experience as if what to come next. If you feel pounding heart, just notice as you know, if scare, just mentally note "scare". That's it. Dhamma will lead you. Do believe Dhamma will show you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is the ensure you are aware of craving occurring in any of the six senses.

For example, your bed in which you sleep might give you "comfort" and you are likely to appreciate it as "good" and think "this comfort is me", or "this comfort is mine", or "this comfort is experienced by my soul".

Most of vipassana is about identifying and removing such false view. To do this, one needs to be aware of what is going on in all six senses.

Comment: suppose one have pain in his leg, would do a vipassana meditator thinks, anyways pain would still be there, I would rather try to distract my mind to something fun so that mind may not feel the pain. But instead if i focus on pain will make it worse i think.

Comment: Physical pain is very hard. Of all people I do understand the need for distraction. I believe most of us do try to distract ourselves in case of pain. May I suggest a more meritorious alternative to fun, as a distraction?

Comment: Please never go away from pain. You will have the same experience if you come back to the same concentration level. Throughout the samsara, what you did will reveal in your insight meditation. Just observe attentively and patiently. Surely you will not die of this pain. And nothing is permanent, you will see it.